# How to check connection services when using webservices?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my app I'm using webservices and if internet connection is true, my app runs very good. 
Without internet my application generates an error. So how can I check internet connection before my application is connected to services. Because I cannot work with applications tuogn although I did

```
try {} 
catch {}
```

So, my app is errors in servicesReferent. How do I do if the case does not have an internet connection, or faulty services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [GetIsNetworkAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in the [NetworkInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k056bfdz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class from the [System.Net.NetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ew4thdx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) namespace

for example

```
   bool isNetworkAvaiable =  NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

Comment: @thongaduka use the tick (✔) mark next to the post, to select the post as answer - if the post answered your question. Cheers !

Comment: why ?Please help me 
bool isNetworkAvaiable =  NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
always is return True ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967560%28v=vs.92%29.aspx Look under the "network information" section, this call can take a really long time. I run it on a background thread and use a join with some reasonable timeout, say 1500ms. If the timeout elapses before there's a result, I assume there's a connection, try the request, and catch any errors.

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that if you connect a WP7 to your development workstation using the USB cable, it will use your workstation's internet connection and this is almost certainly why you always see the network as being available when you are debugging. Disconnecting your workstation from the local network won't help because from the phone's perspective it's still connected to a network (containing two hosts, itself and your workstation) even when that network doesn't have a gateway to anything else.