# how to check InternetConnection in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, internet-connection

i want to check internet connection in my application.but, its not displaying properly.

i am using this code for internet connection:

```
 NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```

in this code always return true value.if net available or not available return true only.

if anyone know tell me idea to do this.

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check connection services when using webservices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147489/how-to-check-connection-services-when-using-webservices)

Comment: It proposes the same answer. So tired of false duplicates.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check **NetworkInterfaceType**. If Internet is available then It should be other than **None**

```
 return (Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != 
 Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterfaceType.None);
```

Comment: NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();NetworkInterface.Equal(); NetworkInterface.RefenceEqual(); showing this 3 option only. NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType this option not avialble check it.

Comment: It's in Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation namespace. You are probably using System.Net.NetworkInformation and looking there

Comment: Any idea why calling this from WP8 emulator with no network makes VS and the emulator not respond for 10-15 seconds?

Answer (score 6):

In the Windows Phone Emulator it's correct that NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() will always return true. Even if your PC has no internet connection, the emulator counts the local/internal connection to your PC.

The return value will be false if you test your application on a real device and switch it e.g. in flight-mode.

Answer (score 3):

Yes NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() will always return true on windows phone emulator you can try below code to detect network availability.

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;    
    if (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("network available") ;              
    }
    else
    {
    MessageBox.Show("No network.") ;   
    }
```